# INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Increment Syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to increment a value from one table to another but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Can someone help me form a correct statement? Thank you in advance:

Current statement:

```
INSERT INTO points_1_day (nick, amount) 
(SELECT nick, SUM(amount) as increment 
FROM points_log 
WHERE dt >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 day GROUP BY nick) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
points_1_day.amount=points_1_day.amount+points_log.increment;
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'points_log.increment' in 'field list'
```

Comment: It's just `increment` - although that may not be the only problem !?!

Comment: @Strawberry If I use increment I get ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'increment' in 'field list'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions in the ON UPDATE clause cannot refer to columns from the SELECT.

But they can refer to `VALUES(amount)` to get the value that you tried to insert on a given row.

```
INSERT INTO points_1_day (nick, amount) 
(SELECT nick, SUM(amount) as increment 
FROM points_log 
WHERE dt >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 day GROUP BY nick) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
points_1_day.amount=points_1_day.amount+VALUES(amount);
```

Let me test this and see if it works...

```
mysql> insert into points_1_day values (123, 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into points_log (nick, amount, dt) values (123, 15, NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> select * from points_1_day;
+------+--------+
| nick | amount |
+------+--------+
|  123 |     10 |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO points_1_day (nick, amount)  (SELECT nick, SUM(amount) as increment  
    FROM points_log  WHERE dt >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 day GROUP BY nick)  
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  points_1_day.amount=points_1_day.amount+values(amount);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from points_1_day;
+------+--------+
| nick | amount |
+------+--------+
|  123 |     25 |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO points_1_day (nick, amount)  (SELECT nick, SUM(amount) as increment  
    FROM points_log  WHERE dt >= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 day GROUP BY nick)  
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  points_1_day.amount=points_1_day.amount+values(amount);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from points_1_day;
+------+--------+
| nick | amount |
+------+--------+
|  123 |     40 |
+------+--------+
```

Yes, it seems to work.

---

Explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html says:

> You can use the `VALUES(col_name`) function in the `UPDATE` clause to
>   refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. In other words, 
>   `VALUES(col_name)` in
>   the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause refers to the value of col_name
>   that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This
>   function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The `VALUES()`
>   function is meaningful only in `INSERT ... UPDATE` statements and
>   returns NULL otherwise. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
> ```

This works with `INSERT...SELECT` too. But the argument to `VALUES()` is the column name you're inserting into, not the name of the corresponding column from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Hm, I agree with the diagnosis - I'm suspicious about the cure

Comment: @Bill-Karwin - That does work as expected! Can you explain the VALUES statement you added? I'm trying to learn MySQL and I'm curious on why this works.